Considering the facade shouldn't have any logic, can I transform the incoming object as the services needs?
Considering the facade shouldn't have logic, passing it to services,does this code uses the facade pattern correctly? I'm doing a map and grouping the data and using the return in other services that needs it.
public List<OrderOutput> checkout(ListOfOrderInput listOfOrderInput){
        var orderList = listOfOrderInput.mapToOrderList();
        var orderItems = orderList.stream()
                .flatMap(order->order.getItems()
                        .stream())
                .toList();
        var groupedOrders = orderSupplyService.groupsOrders(orderList);
        orderSupplyService.setsOrderListData(groupedOrders);
        orderItemService.setItemsCode(groupedOrders);
        itemAmountCalculatorService.calculateDesiredAmount(groupedOrders);

        var ordersToInsert = orderService
                .buildsDistinctOrderList(orderList);

        orderSupplyService.registerOrderList(ordersToInsert);
        orderItemService.registerOrderItems(ordersToInsert);
        orderSupplyService.checkoutOrders(ordersToInsert);

        var orderReturnList = orderReturnService.getOrderReturnList(ordersToInsert);
        orderReturnItemService.buildsOrdersReturnItems(orderReturnList);

        orderFacadeIntegration.sendCreatedOrders(orderReturnList.stream()
                .map(OrderModel::mapToOrderIntegration)
                .toList());

        return orderReturnList.stream()
                .map(OrderModel::mapToOrderOutput)
                .toList();
    }


Can you link to a source for the assertion that a facade shouldn't have logic?

@jaco0646 that's the way we do it here, logic only in the services

The GoF patterns do not enforce or promote any such layering. Whether this code abides by your team's internal conventions is therefore up to your team to determine. As an aside, I would note that the (popular) separation between services  and DTOs is effectively the opposite of OOP. Data-less services which hoard all of an application's logic are effectively utilities, while the anemic DTOs they transform are effectively data structs. These are the twin building blocks of procedural programming rather than OOP.

Considering the facade shouldn't have logic
I would argue that based on the one problems the Facade pattern can solve:


to make a complex subsystem easier to use, a simple interface should be provided for a set of interfaces in the subsystem.


It is bound to contain some amount of logic. Reshaping the data so it can be passed to the objects hidden under facade is perfectly fine.
Also I would say you should not worry about names that much - design patterns should be considered as general principles and it is perfectly fine to not follow them to a tee. The main objective is to produce maintainable and reusable software and while naming things correctly is useful it is not the goal.
